# How to perform like search in multiple language's json?

Tags: php, mysql

We are having following data under name filed:

```json
{
  "en":"Nokia-130",
  "ar":"\u0646\u0648\u0643\u064a\u0627 130 (2017)",
  "ch":"\u8bfa\u57fa\u4e9a130\uff082017\uff09"
}
```

We are trying to hit:

```mysql
SELECT json_extract(NAME, "$.ar")
FROM products
WHERE json_extract(NAME, "$.ar") LIKE '%\u0646%';
```

it works fine and gives the result but when we hit

```mysql
SELECT json_extract(NAME, "$.ar")
FROM products
WHERE json_extract(NAME, "$.ar") LIKE '%\u0646\u0648%';
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: This looks like an encoding and/or escape problem. Can you output the result of `SELECT @@collation_connection, json_extract(NAME, "$.ar"), NAME, '%\u0646%' FROM products WHERE json_extract(NAME, "$.ar") LIKE '%\u0646%';` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
    ->   `NAME` JSON
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `products`
    ->   (`NAME`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('{
    '>       "en":"Nokia-130",
    '>       "ar":"\u0646\u0648\u0643\u064a\u0627 130 (2017)",
    '>       "ch":"\u8bfa\u57fa\u4e9a130\uff082017\uff09"
    '>     }');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `NAME` -> "$.ar"
    -> FROM `products`
    -> WHERE `NAME` -> "$.ar" LIKE '%\u0646%';
+----------------------------------------+
| `NAME` -> "$.ar"                       |
+----------------------------------------+
| "u0646u0648u0643u064au0627 130 (2017)" |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `NAME` -> "$.ar"
    -> FROM `products`
    -> WHERE `NAME` -> "$.ar" LIKE '%\u0646\u0648%';
+----------------------------------------+
| `NAME` -> "$.ar"                       |
+----------------------------------------+
| "u0646u0648u0643u064au0627 130 (2017)" |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w1jMLc38vnPGE88Qxy57Uu/0).

Comment: {"en":"Definitions of google","ar":"\u062a\u0639\u0631\u064a\u0641\u0627\u062a \u062c\u0648\u062c\u0644","ch":"google\u7684\u5b9a\u4e49"} checkout for this not working space

Comment: @harshal: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bGT3MzodACneJFEvP4RsK1/0).